# Edge scrolling is working fine but two finger scrolling had stopped working?

Tags: xorg, touchpad, synaptics, scrolling

After reinstalling xorg, my two finger scrolling of the touchpad stopped working though edge scrolling is working perfectly. I tried different solutions but none of them work.

My original /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-synaptics.conf file is

```
# Example xorg.conf.d snippet that assigns the touchpad driver
# to all touchpads. See xorg.conf.d(5) for more information on
# InputClass.
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE, your distribution will likely overwrite
# it when updating. Copy (and rename) this file into
# /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d first.
# Additional options may be added in the form of
#   Option "OptionName" "value"
#
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "touchpad catchall"
        Driver "synaptics"
        MatchIsTouchpad "on"
# This option is recommend on all Linux systems using evdev, but cannot be
# enabled by default. See the following link for details:
# http://who-t.blogspot.com/2010/11/how-to-ignore-configuration-errors.html
      MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
EndSection

Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "touchpad ignore duplicates"
        MatchIsTouchpad "on"
        MatchOS "Linux"
        MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/mouse*"
        Option "Ignore" "on"
EndSection
```

I performed the following modification as suggested at different places but still problem persist.

```
# Example xorg.conf.d snippet that assigns the touchpad driver
# to all touchpads. See xorg.conf.d(5) for more information on
# InputClass.
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE, your distribution will likely overwrite
# it when updating. Copy (and rename) this file into
# /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d first.
# Additional options may be added in the form of
#   Option "OptionName" "value"
#
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier "touchpad catchall"
    Driver "synaptics"
    MatchIsTouchpad "on"
    # This option is recommend on all Linux systems using evdev, but cannot be
    # enabled by default. See the following link for details:
    # http://who-t.blogspot.com/2010/11/how-to-ignore-configuration-errors.html
    MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
    Option "TapButton1" "1"
    Option "TapButton2" "2"
    Option "TapButton3" "3"
    Option "VertEdgeScroll" "on"
    Option "VertTwoFingerScroll" "on"
    Option "HorizEdgeScroll" "on"
    Option "HorizTwoFingerScroll" "on"
    Option "CircularScrolling" "on"
    Option "CircScrollTrigger" "2"
    Option "EmulateTwoFingerMinZ" "40"
    Option "EmulateTwoFingerMinW" "8"
    Option "CoastingSpeed" "0"
    Option "FingerLow" "35"
    Option "FingerHigh" "40"
EndSection

Section "InputClass"
    Identifier "touchpad ignore duplicates"
    MatchIsTouchpad "on"
    MatchOS "Linux"
    MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/mouse*"
    Option "Ignore" "on"
EndSection
```

My Xorg.0.log looks like this.

```
[    22.912] (II) config/udev: Adding input device ImPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad (/dev/input/event6)
[    22.912] (**) ImPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: Applying InputClass "evdev pointer catchall"
[    22.912] (**) ImPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: Applying InputClass "evdev pointer catchall"
[    22.912] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'ImPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad'
[    22.912] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/evdev_drv.so
[    22.912] (**) ImPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: always reports core events
[    22.912] (**) evdev: ImPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: Device: "/dev/input/event6"
[    22.912] (--) evdev: ImPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: Vendor 0x2 Product 0x5
[    22.912] (--) evdev: ImPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: Found 3 mouse buttons
[    22.912] (--) evdev: ImPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: Found scroll wheel(s)
[    22.912] (--) evdev: ImPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: Found relative axes
[    22.912] (--) evdev: ImPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: Found x and y relative axes
[    22.912] (II) evdev: ImPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: Configuring as mouse
[    22.912] (II) evdev: ImPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: Adding scrollwheel support
[    22.912] (**) evdev: ImPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: YAxisMapping: buttons 4 and 5
[    22.912] (**) evdev: ImPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: EmulateWheelButton: 4, EmulateWheelInertia: 10, EmulateWheelTimeout: 200
[    22.912] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/platform/i8042/serio1/input/input6/event6"
[    22.912] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "ImPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad" (type: MOUSE, id 11)
[    22.912] (II) evdev: ImPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: initialized for relative axes.
[    22.912] (**) ImPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: (accel) keeping acceleration scheme 1
[    22.912] (**) ImPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: (accel) acceleration profile 0
[    22.912] (**) ImPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: (accel) acceleration factor: 2.000
[    22.912] (**) ImPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: (accel) acceleration threshold: 4
[    22.912] (II) config/udev: Adding input device ImPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad (/dev/input/mouse1)
[    22.912] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    22.912] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the value for the "VertTwoFingerScroll" option with

```
synclient VertTwoFingerScroll=1
```

Comment: Can't use synclinet. Error Msg: Couldn't find synaptics properties. No synaptics driver loaded?

Comment: You probably need to install new packages (which will depend on the type of laptop and version of Ubuntu).  Likely candidates are: xf86-input-synaptics, libsynaptics, or xserver-xorg-input-synaptics.  Take a look with `aptitude search synap`